# Set the two tables to page width in two-column mode

Tags: tables, two-column

[image]

I want to generate the kind of table above the picture. There are two tables in total, and they occupy the width of the page in two-column mode. When I use the following code, the results are not the same as I thought, they are displayed in different lines. Is there any way to display it as shown in the figure? Thank you!

```
\begin{table*}[t]
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.3\linewidth}
        \begin{center}
            \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
                \hline
            nums    & W         & L       \\ \hline
                1 (k/ms) & 0  & 0  \\ \hline
                2 (k/ms)  & 0  & 0   \\ \hline
                3 (k/ms) & 0  & 0  \\ \hline
                Total (k/ms) & 0  & 0   \\ \hline
            \end{tabular}
            \caption{Process.}
            \label{table:formatting}
        \end{center}
    \end{minipage}%
    
    
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.7\linewidth}
        \begin{center}
            \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|}
                \hline
                & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}L1 WB\\ \& Alg.1\end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}sender\\ \& g++\end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}sender\\ only\end{tabular} \\ \hline
                D & 0\%                                                  & 0\%                                                 & 0\%                                               \\ \hline
                L  & 06\%                                                  & 0\%                                                & 0\%                                              \\ \hline
                C & 0\%                                                 & 0\%                                                & 0\%                                              \\ \hline
            \end{tabular}
            \caption{Algorithm 1.}
            \label{table:formatting}
        \end{center}
    \end{minipage}%

    
    \caption{Example sequences }
\end{table*}
```

Comment: The tables in your example are narrow enough to fit into one column of text, each. There is no need to let one of them occupy 0.7\textwidth. Even table 6 in the screenshot in your question could, with some careful redesigning, fit into one text column or could be combined with table 7 into a two column wide table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is fine. Only three minor changes are needed. Try one by one to see their effect.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{showframe}

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{table*}[t]
%       \begin{minipage}[t]{0.3\linewidth}
        \begin{minipage}{0.3\linewidth} %changed <<<<<<<<<<<<
            \begin{center}
                \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
                    \hline
                    nums    & W         & L       \\ \hline
                    1 (k/ms) & 0  & 0  \\ \hline
                    2 (k/ms)  & 0  & 0   \\ \hline
                    3 (k/ms) & 0  & 0  \\ \hline
                    Total (k/ms) & 0  & 0   \\ \hline
                \end{tabular}
                \caption{Process.}
                \label{table:formatting}
            \end{center}
        \end{minipage}% 
    %% remove blank lines <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
%       \begin{minipage}[t]{0.7\linewidth}
        \begin{minipage}{0.7\linewidth} %changed <<<<<<<<<<<
            \begin{center}
                \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|}
                    \hline
                    & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}L1 WB\\ \& Alg.1\end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}sender\\ \& g++\end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}sender\\ only\end{tabular} \\ \hline
                    D & 0\%                                                  & 0\%                                                 & 0\%                                               \\ \hline
                    L  & 06\%                                                  & 0\%                                                & 0\%                                              \\ \hline
                    C & 0\%                                                 & 0\%                                                & 0\%                                              \\ \hline
                \end{tabular}
                \caption{Algorithm 1.}
                \label{table:formatting}
            \end{center}
        \end{minipage}%
        \caption{Example sequences }
    \end{table*} 
    
\end{document}
```

[image: m]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But what have you changed in my code? I just checked it and found no changes. But the code you gave is valid, but the code I wrote is not.

Comment: Sorry I didn't comment on the code. See the updated answer.